# Replace many arbitrary markdown links with grep/sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, markdown

I have a large set of markdown files that I need to go through and replace many of the links. Each link that needs replacing is preceded by the same string, say `Foo bar`, and then the customary markdown link syntax follows: `[arbitrary name](address)`. For example,

```
Foo bar [arbitrary link text](http://arbitrary.address.com)
```

I need to find each markdown link after "Foo bar " and change the address in the parentheses to a different link, say `foo.bar.com`. The problem is that each link is different, and the arbitrary link text must be preserved, so I can't just grep a string and replace it. How can I use grep to identify the files with the matching pattern and sed to replace the links?

Comment: what do you already try that doesn't work as you want ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `find` command.

```
find . -type f -exec sed -ri 's/\b(Foo bar +\[[^\]]*\]\()[^()]*\)/\1foo.bar.com)/g' {} \;
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to be replacing the (address) with foo.bar.com, but it's matching the files correctly.

Comment: you need to add -i param to save the changes made.Now try my update and let me know whether it works or not..